# Show that set of natural numbers with zero ordered by division is complete lattice.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, natural-numbers

I have to prove thatthe set of non-negative numbers ordered by division in complete lattice by showing that every non-empty subset of non-negative numbers has infimum.
I know that infimum  of finite set is given by greatest common divisor, but how to prove it? In {1,2,3} infimum is 1, but what is infimum in {2,3,4}?

Comment: Hint: the infimum of a finite set in a *partial* order need not be an element of the set.

Comment: Wow, it's clear now, because every pair of numbers has gcd. thank you!

Comment: Yep, and not just pairs of numbers!